# Ask for publish permissions at the same time as read for achievements

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am working on a game that has achievements, I just discovered that in order to unlock achievements for a user you need to have publish_actions permission. I also understand that it's against Facebook policies to ask for both read and publish permissions up front when the user logs in. However I can't see any other way when I need it for achievements, otherwise when a user unlocks and achievement mid game I would have to prompt them for publish permissions. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can request both read and publish permissions in the same call to FB.Login with the Unity SDK.  That said, it's a better experience for the user if you split them up and request publish permissions when they are going to be used.

Comment: The method is deprecated by now. I guess the double-login is the only way to do it now.

Answer (score 1):

Me to had faced same problem before. Best Way to tackle it by separating both the permissions.
**Separate them as follows:**
 1. At the time of login, ask for the **read permissions**. and then,
 2. When you are going to publish a story for the ***first time***, ask
    for the **publish permission**. 
You can do this simply by calling the login function again with the new permission nothing complicated.

You may want to repost your question at Unity Answers as it gets a lot more traffic and it's more likely to be answered: http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html

**I Hope this will help you a lot... If yes the Do accept it as answer :) and mark it as useful as well.**

Comment: The only problem is that the user can get an achievement right in the middle of game play, so it would be a terrible interruption to ask them for a Facebook permission at that time.

Comment: @mcdon0 Indeed it will be like interruption, but not terrible at all as you will ask them the **publish permissions first time only!**
And its perfectly legal as well as ethical as you are concerned about user and you wisely asking them Publish(ing) permissions before publishing anything to their wall.